# Filebeat don't send info logs

Tags: logging, filebeat

How can I set in filebeat if I want all other logs but not info. 
This is my configuration but this one doesn't work:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/messages
    - /var/log/secure
    - /var/log/audit/audit.log
    - /var/log/yum.log
    - /root/.bash_history
    - /var/log/neutron/*.log
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
    - /var/log/keystone/keystone.log
    - /var/log/httpd/error_log
    - /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
    - /var/log/glance/*.log
    - /var/log/rabbitmq/*.log
  exclude_files: ['/var/log/neutron/metadata-agent.log$']
  ignore_older: 72h
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/neutron/metadata-agent.log
  level: error
  ignore_older: 72h
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
output.logstash:
  hosts: [""]
```

My goal is in case of the metadata-agent.log I don't want to send the info logs, only everything else which is different from info like these:

```
2019-03-18 12:34:18.075 1183 TRACE neutron.agent.metadata.agent Exception: Unexpected response code: 504
2019-03-18 12:34:18.075 1183 TRACE neutron.agent.metadata.agent
2019-03-18 12:34:19.083 1186 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent [-] Unexpected error.
```

But with this configuration the info is still sending. Where is the problem?
My filebeat version is 6.2

Answer (score 0):

> You can define processors in your configuration to process events
>   before they are sent to the configured output

You can use [drop_event](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.5/drop-event.html) processor under [Processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.5/configuration-processors.html#configuration-processors) section in `filebeat.yml` as below, It will drop any log line that coming from `/var/log/neutron/metadata-agent.log` file and regular expression matches line start with ex: `2019-03-18 12:34:18.075 1183 INFO`

> The `drop_event` processor drops the entire event if the associated
>   condition is fulfilled

```
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - drop_event:
     when:
      and:
        - equals:
           source: '/var/log/neutron/metadata-agent.log'
        - regexp:
           message: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s\d{4}\sINFO\s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat 7.x -- you can just use exclude_lines

- Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
- matching any regular expression from the list. The include_lines is called before
- exclude_lines. By default, no lines are dropped.
  exclude_lines: ['^DBG']

Source: [Filebeat Prospectors, *exclude_lines*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.3/configuration-filebeat-options.html#exclude-lines)